# excel: run time error 9 when running form

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet called BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS with five columns of information that I want to fill with a form that I created using this code below. I can type all informations and I associated this code with the "Insert" button:

```
Private Sub inserirInfo_Click()
Dim LastRow As Range
Dim ExpenseTable As ListObject

'Add row to bottom of BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS table  

Worksheets("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").Activate.ListObjects("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").ListRows.Add


'Enter data from form into our new row
Set ExpenseTable = Worksheets("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").Activate.ListObjects("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS")
Set LastRow = ExpenseTable.ListRows(ExpenseTable.ListRows.Count).Range

With LastRow

    .Cells(1, 1) = cmbMatricula.Value
    .Cells(1, 2) = cmbNome.Value
    .Cells(1, 3) = cmbFuncao.Value
    .Cells(1, 4) = txtAlocacao.Value
    .Cells(1, 5) = txtDataIni.Value
    .Cells(1, 6) = txtDataFim.Value


End With
End Sub
```

My form is placed in a different sheet than the sheet I'll fill with information. Anyway, when I run the code I keep getting **Run-Time Error 9** that highlights this part of code:

```
Worksheets("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").Activate.ListObjects("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").ListRows.Add
```

I was thinking of using "ActivateSheet" instead of Worksheets("").Activate, but I really don't know how to solve this problem. Anyone could help?

Comment: `.Activate` doesn't return anything, you can't chain calls like you're doing. And you don't need to `.Activate` anyway, just remove it and do `Worksheets("name").ListObjects("name").ListRows.Add` instead.

Comment: Also, make sure your string literals don't contain typos and that the user doesn't rename these sheets/tables, otherwise you get exactly the error you're getting: *subscript out of range*.

Comment: Actually the table doesn't have the same name as the sheet. I was thinking in a way os referencing without put a name on it, but it seems that I can't as you said

Comment: If there's only 1 table on that sheet just do `.ListObjects(1)`

Comment: @Mat'sMug in fact there are two tables, but the first has BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS name now and still doesn't work... I'll try to insert my second table in another sheet to check if this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 9 means Subscript out of range i.e. the object you are referring to doesn't exist in the workbook/worksheet.

Make sure you have a sheet called "BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS" in the workbook and on that sheet, you have an excel table named "BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS".

Other than that, the correct syntax would be like this...    `Worksheets("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").ListObjects("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").ListRows.Add`

Same way the second line would be like this...

```
Set ExpenseTable = Worksheets("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS").ListObjects("BASE_GERAL_FUNCIONARIOS")
```

Comment: actually, my table doesn't have this name... Only the sheet has. Is there a way to make reference without changing table's name?

Comment: You can refer the table by the index number, so if the sheet has only one table you can refer it by .ListObjects(1)

Comment: I got it! is there any way to do this type of reference when I have two tables in the same sheet?

Comment: Yes. Use the index of the target table only. To get the table details run this code.... Sub GetTableIndex()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
If .ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To .ListObjects.Count
        'open Immediate window by pressing Ctrl+G to read the table details
        Debug.Print .ListObjects(i).Name & "  Table Index - " & i
    Next i
End If
End With
End Sub